# TransitionDelegate and MVVMCross

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, uikit-transitions

I'm trying to implement my custom transition beetween views with    IUIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate. This is my TableViewController

```
public class TableListView : MvxTableViewController, IUIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
{
...
[Export ("animationControllerForPresentedController:presentingController:sourceController:")]
        public MonoTouch.UIKit.IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning PresentingController (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController presented, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController presenting, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController source)
{
...
}

[Export ("animationControllerForDismissedController:")]
public  MonoTouch.UIKit.IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning GetAnimationControllerForDismissedController (MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController dismissed)
{
...
    }
}
```

but when from core i show another ViewModel, GetAnimationControllerForDismissedController or PresentingController (when itself is showed) are not invoked...

Here an example with monotouch 
https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/TransitionsDemo

Comment: Can you show your navigation controller or presenter - whatever is doing the equivalent of https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/TransitionsDemo/TransitionsDemo/NavigationController.cs

Comment: I tryed the sample, it does not work ! Well it works only if setting animation from navigation controller, but not from viewcontroller (ie: settings) !